# How can I get the client credentials in a WCF Data Service

Tags: authentication, wcf-data-services

I need help on how to retrieve username and password from a calling client in a WCF Data Service. The client (Android) is accessing the WCF Data Service using basic auth over https which is handled by the IIS. The WCF Data Service then needs to access a asmx service, for this I need to specify Network Credentials, ie username and password. One way would be to specify username and password as input parameters for the service operations on the WCF Data Service but I think it would be cleaner if you could get the credentials from the http request somehow?

Comment: You could switch to forms authentication, another option is to look into impersonation and kerberos double-hop delegation, both of these are more secure than using username/password as input parameters (which if both specified in a URL are entirely insecure even via HTTPS).